# Find data between two given value in Nodejs & Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, filter

I am trying to find data between two given heights. I am storing heights data in separate Mongodb schema, in which the height's unique `_id` is what I store in a `user-schema`. So I do populate() in the GET Apis and all.

The problem is when I am working on the filter api like finding users based on given two heights, How can I find the users data between two input height?   should I pass the two heights `_id` to find ? If so may i know the method or some suggestion or Raw data like 5.1 to 6? If I pass raw data like 5.1 and 5.8 but how will I find users data because I am not storing raw data in `user-schema` instead I am storing height's id.

**Config Schema**

```
const appconfigSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    configValue: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    configDesc: {
        type: String,
    },
...
```

**Config Sample Data**

```
[
        {
            "_id": "636261302187d07f920b1174",
            "configValue": "5.1",
            "configDesc": "5ft 1in",
            "metaDataType": "Height",
            "isParent": false,
            "parentPrimaryId": "636260f82187d07f920b1171",
            "isActive": true,
            "createdAt": "2022-11-02T12:23:12.999Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-11-02T12:23:12.999Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
```

**User Schema**

```
...
Height: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'appconfigs'
    },
...
```

**User Sample Data**

```
...
    "Country": "India",
    "State": "Tamil Nadu",
    "City": "Trichy",
    "Height": "636261302187d07f920b1174",
...
```

So How to find users data between two given heights ? Should I pass heights Id only or heights raw data like 5.1 & 5.8, If so please teach me the method

Comment: Have you tried using an aggregation pipeline, where you first use `$lookup` to populate the config Height property and afterwards using a simple `$match` step to find all documents with the desired filter criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with your use case and figured out this solution. Hope it helps.

```
const filteredUsers = await User.aggregate([
  // Lookup to get height information from ID 
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "configs", // Looking in the config table
      localField: "Height",
      foreignField: "_id",
      pipeline: [{
        // Convert value to double (was string)
        $project: {
          valueAsDouble: {$toDouble: "$configValue"}
        }
      }],
      as: "heightLookup"
   }
  },
  {
    // Match users with condition 5.1 <= Height value <= 5.8
    $match: {
      "heightLookup.0.valueAsDouble": {$gte: 5.1, $lte: 5.8}
    }
  } 
]);

// Expected output

[
  {
    "City": "Trichy",
    "Country": "India",
    "Height": "636261302187d07f920b1174",
    "State": "Tamil Nadu",
    "_id": 1,
    "heightLookup": [
      {
        "_id": "636261302187d07f920b1174",
        "valueAsDouble": 5.1
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks man, its working. So is this the way for multi filters also ? Ex: Now we are doing for height only, Actually I have more fields to filter such as Religion, age, height, salary, etc.. So Would it same ? can you add any sample ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know both _id of heights and want to fetch all documents between these _ids then both ids will be enough to find data and you can find them like this.

```
const userData=await users.find({$and:[{"Height._id":{$gte:"smaller_id"}},{"Height._id":{$lte:"larger_id"}}]});
```